# Turning off audit trails of AWS CloudTrail

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudtrail

AWS CloudTrail Events has a feature which turns on audit trails automatically in AWS account and keeps the data for couple of days. Due to some compliance, want this feature to be turned off.

1. Is there any way to turn this off?
2. Is there any API to delete the logs?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible and is implied by this FAQ response:

> Q: Can I turn CloudTrail Event History off for my account?
>
> **For any CloudTrail trails that you have created, you can stop logging or delete the trails** which will also stop the delivery of account activity to the S3 bucket you had designated as part of your trail configuration as well as delivery to CloudWatch Logs if configured. Account activity for the past 90 days **will still be collected and visible** within the CloudTrail console and through the AWS CLI.